# Casting keeps on getting errors

Tags: c#, casting, double

I have a CSV with the following data (no header)

```
12,2010,76.5
2,2000,45
12,1940,30.2
```

and I'm reading the data into a `List<List<object>>`.

To know what's in each line and column / row I'm using the following loop

```
List<List<object>> data = CSVReaderNoHeader.Read("input")

for (var i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
{

    double month = (double)(int)data[i][0];
    print($"month:{month} ////END");

    double year= (double)(int)data[i][1];
    print($"year:{year} ////END");

    double temperature= (double)data[i][2];
    print($"temperature:{temperature} ////END");

}
```

Yes I need to create doubles, that's why I'm unboxing and casting (could have use `double.Parse` instead).

I'm able to print the month and the year just fine, but when reaching `double temperature= (double)data[i][2];`, throws the following error

> InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

I printed what's in data[i][2] before that line (`print(data[i][2]);`) just to see if everything was in order there and got *76.5* as expected. Then, tested also using

```
double temperature= (double)(double)data[i][2];
double temperature= (double)(float)data[i][2];
```

(which i think it would be unnecessary to add that extra (double) / (float)) and

```
object tempr = data[i][2];
double temperature;
temperature = (double)tempr;
```

but the problem remained. So, I went on and ran `print(data[i][2].GetType());` to see if the type returned there could be cast into a double. I got as result *System.String*.

Knowing this, then I tried then the methods double.TryParse, double.Parse and Convert.ToDouble but none worked

```
double.TryParse(data[i][2], out temperature);
```

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to string.

```
double temperature = double.TryParse(data[i][2]);
```

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to string.

```
double temperature = System.Convert.ToDouble(data[i][2]);
```

> FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

How then I have to cast it?

Comment: I see "System.String".

Comment: Try using the InvariantCulture: `double.TryParse(data[i][2], NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out temperature);`. It might be that in your local culture that is used by default the delimiter for double is `,` not `.`

Comment: With InvariantCulture I also get `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to string.`

Comment: And if you do: `double.TryParse(data[i][2].ToString(), NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out temperature);` ?

Comment: That works @Fabjan, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: @Fabjan Do you want to write as an answer or shall I accept the one from Olivier Rogier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your numbers use a point as decimal separator and your system localization can use a different, you can use that:

```
using System.Xml;

double temperature = XmlConvert.ToDouble(data[i][2].ToString());
```

It will raise an exception in case of parsing error.

So you can try...catch to manage it.

Perhaps you will need to add System.Xml to assembly references of the project.

Else you can use @Fabjan solution:

```
if (double.TryParse(data[i][2].ToString(),
                    System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any,
                    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    out var temperature);
  IsOk();
else
  IsNotOk();
```